# Add local storage to Flash webapp

Tags: flash, web-applications, air, local-storage

I would like to add local storage to an existing Flash webapp that up until now uses a web server to store data (database and media files).

What are my options? I'd like to reuse the code of the Flash webapp and run it inside a browser if possible (which, if I'm not mistaken, is not possible with Adobe AIR).

Answer (score 0):

Your options are limited, but the primary way for flash to store data locally is a [Local Shared Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object), aka "Flash Cookie".

They have all the same issues as normal cookies, along with a few more.

The code is simple though:

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;

var cookie:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal('mycookiename', '/', false);
cookie.data.foo = 'bar';
cookie.flush(1);
```

You can read all about it on the [flash api](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html).

Alternatively, you can use `ExternalInterface` in conjunction with JavaScript to access/mutate data in regular cookies.

Comment: Doesn't that have a 100KB limit? If so it's not enough to store media files.

Comment: It's not for media file storage. It's just a way of storing data locally. With flash you can't directly store data on a users local file system because it's in a different security sandbox. AIR can interact with the local filesystem, but has the issues you'd mentioned. You can use server scripting to serve files to the user if you just want them to be able to save locally.